# YAML.load never returns in Rails initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, yaml, initializer, syck, psych

I'm trying to load a yaml config file during initialization of my Rails 3.1 app, and the call to YAML.load never returns.  Here is my initializer file:

```
STRIPE_CONFIG = begin
  config = YAML.load(Rails.root.join('config', 'stripe.yml')) || {}
  config = config[Rails.env] || {}
  config.to_options
end
```

And here is my stripe.yml file:

```
default: &default
  api_key:    test
  public_key: test

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default

production:
  api_key:    prod
  public_key: prod
```

For whatever reason, the `YAML.load` call never returns.  If I perform a stack trace, it seems to be stuck on syck.rb line 135.  The interesting thing is, the longer I let my app sit before breaking, the more calls to line 135 appear.

```
/Users/mhuggins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `read'
/Users/mhuggins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `read'
/Users/mhuggins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load'
/Users/mhuggins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load'
/Users/mhuggins/Sites/dating/config/initializers/stripe.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
...
```

I've tried explicitly using Psych as well instead of using Syck, but with no luck.  (It ends up hanging as well.)

```
STRIPE_CONFIG = begin
  require 'psych'
  config = Psych.load(Rails.root.join('config', 'stripe.yml')) || {}
  config = config[Rails.env] || {}
  config.to_options
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ugh, apparently I just needed to explicitly read the file.  I changed this:

```
YAML.load(Rails.root.join('config', 'stripe.yml'))
```

to this:

```
YAML.load(File.open(Rails.root.join('config', 'stripe.yml')))
```

Answer (score 4):

Answer will be kinda late, but I have stumbled upon similar problem just now ;)

You could use `YAML::load_file`, which expects filename as an argument.